# Use OCR to post answers from PDFs which are not text searchable

Tags: discussion

Sometimes it may be tedious to type all the matter from a non-searchable files. [IndianScriptures](http://www.indianscriptures.com/) is a great site to get any scriptures in both English and Sanskrit. Puranas are also available on [WestBengal Dspace](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9095/3500) but only in English and that too in non-text searchable format. I found two methods to post answers from non-searchable documents.

**1.** **Google Drive OCR (accurate and the best method):**

In this method, upload the PDF (size must be below 10MB) to drive. Right Click on file - Open with  Google docs.

[image]

In next tab, document will be opened in text searchable format. We can scan Devanagari with this method and accuracy is very good. No other OCR tools can scan Devanagari, even the paid software. Limitations of this method is, it will only allow upto 10MB file and if you have chunk of big file you need to split into a smaller file by using Splitting tools. [PDFsam Basic](http://www.pdfsam.org/downloads/) can do this work for windows and you can use other tools for other platforms. Also, Google Drive OCR won't scan image files and you need to convert the image to PDF using ImagetoPdf converter tools.

**2. Microsoft Onenote OCR :**

This method can be used to scan Puranas from dspace. Accuracy of recognition is good but not great. This method cannot recognize Devanagari. To do this, take screenshot of text you want to scan using snipping tool (Windows)- copy and paste the image in Microsoft OneNote, which is part of Microsoft office. Right Click and use the option "copy text from Picture".

[image]

There are many free software to this. See these questions. [Free OCR software that makes a PDF searchable (with searchable text at the right place)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/free-ocr-software-that-makes-a-pdf-searchable-with-searchable-text-at-the-right) and [Which tools can turn scanned paper documents into searchable text pdf on Mac?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17593/which-tools-can-turn-scanned-paper-documents-into-searchable-text-pdf-on-mac).

I personally use Google Drive OCR to answer questions from Shiva Purana (Indian Scriptures) which is not searchable. To copy small passages, i use OneNote OCR, though italicized must be edited. But you face no problems in Google Drive OCR.

Comment: good information

Comment: Great job, thanks for sharing.

Comment: FYI: [What is Free Software?](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html), [Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software#Definition_and_the_Four_Freedoms).

Comment: Very nice post , very useful and informative

Comment: @The Destroyer Thanks!  Also, if you have multiple docs, tesseract is very useful.  The command woould be "tesseract veda.pdf veda.txt"  When we run it is a batch file, we can convert multiple. I use this to extract text from photos :)

Comment: This doesn't work now due to changes in the Stack Exchange editor.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma What do you mean by this doesn't work? These OCR tricks has nothing to do with Stack Exchange.

Comment: There are changes to image editor yesterday. After new changes, we can not copy text from picture and post it directly to the editor. My [reported bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317603/357396) got a status declined.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma It works if you paste it as plain text. I tested now with Onenote 2016 on chrome. I will test again after few days as i'm out of town now.