# How to politely ask a user to use text instead of images?

Tags: discussion, post-quality

Related: [Are image-only answers acceptable?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1115/21103)

I understand in certain situations, images are the only way one can express what one wants. But it's not proper to post images when the same thing can be written down. Especially, screenshots of texts which is in English. Most probably, there would be a way out to copy the text. This afternoon, I typed an answer while editing which someone had posted as an image. Later, I realised I could have just used an OCR tool for it.

Anyways,

Text based answers are usually encouraged. Here is an old meta.se post [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/824803)

*While all experienced users of this site would know the reason why images are discouraged, new users reading this post might need to see the linked questions here.*

Instead of just asking it at interpersonal.se, I thought of asking it here so that it becomes a collective effort for the betterment of this site.

- How may we encourage writing questions or answers in text?
- What would be a polite way to ask users to use text instead of images? Any sample messages, etc would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Welcome to the Hinduism Stack Exchange! Though your answer is good as it cites the sources, however texts cited in image form has [some disadvantages](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1115/277) e.g. it's not [searchable](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search) through search engines. **It is recommended to cite the text in text format whenever it's possible.**  You can use OCR tool to extract text from images as explained [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/616/277). So, we encourage you to convert the image citation into text. Feel free to use [our chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) if you're finding it difficult to OCR, users in the chat room would be happy to help you :)

This is a sample comment message, you can customize it.

Comment: +1 for the chatroom link ;-)